# How to retain all form values when using form chaining in a web application?

Tags: php, http, web-applications, forms, pass-through, http-post

I have an html form page that I submit, and resulting page opens to another form that requests supplementary information, in addition to `form 1`.  When I submit the 2nd form, values from the first form are not submitted along with it, so I only get values from `form 2`.

By default I get this:

```
form1 -> [submit] -> form2 -> [submit] -> [result page with form2 values only]
```

How can I receive values from both forms?

In my case 2nd form is dependent on the first, as in it needs to know values from the first form to exist and the forms are not independent.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the data from the first form in session/local storage and post this along with Form2 data. Once, submit is successful, clear the storage.